# Need a SQL solution for licensing system

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

The project in development is a business directory with the following subscription levels:
Platinum, Gold, Silver and Bronze

I have 3 tables that are in question for this task. I will put the important columns in parentheses.

BD_Listing (ListingID, LevelID, Active)

- ListingID, INT, PK
- LevelID, INT 4=bronze, 5=silver, 6=gold, 7=platinum
- Active, BIT

BD_ListingOwner (UserID, ListingID)

- UserID (This is the UserID of the authenticated user)
- ListingID (When the initial listing is created, their UserID and ListingID are entered in this table.

BD_Storefront (RecurringSubscriptionID, Quantity, VariantID, Status)

- RecurringSubscriptionID PK
- Quantity (If they select Gold for example, they can choose more than one license for that level)
- VariantID (These differ slightly from the BD_Listing table. 1=Bronze, 2=Silver, 3=Gold, 4=Platinum)
- Status (True or False)

After purchase, the user is taken to a page where they can begin creating their listing. There is a module on that page that looks like a table:

**Level----------Active/Remaining----------Action**

Platinum------1/0------------------------------Purchase Additional License

Gold-----------0/2------------------------------Create Gold Listing

Silver----------0/0------------------------------Purchase Additional License

Bronze--------0/0------------------------------Purchase Additional License

So basically, I need to understand the correct SQL Query that  does the following:

1. Checks the BD_Storefront table to see how many active listings are attached to the @passedUserID of the person logged in, and to know the available quantity they have for Platinum, Gold, Silver, and Bronze.
2. Check the BD_ListingOwner table to get the number of listings attached to the @passedUserID
3. Check the BD_Listing table in correlation with the BD_ListingOwner table to see the LevelID to know which level types have actually been created, keeping in mind that these integers differ slightly from those that are in the BD_Storefront table.

I need to make sure I get the total quantity of each type, keeping in mind that John may purchase 2 gold in one order, showing Quantity 2 in the BD_Storefront table, and a month later may purchase  another gold, creating another row in the table with the quantity of 1, giving him a total of 3 licenses.

Here's the SQL that I've come up with thus far:

```
SELECT
 a.[RecurringSalesOrderID]
,a.[UserID]
,a.[PortalID]
,a.[ProductVariantID]
,a.[Quantity]
,a.[NextRecurringDate]
,a.[Status]
,a.[OriginalSalesOrderID]
,a.[CreateDate]
,a.[UpdateDate]
,b.[UserID]
,b.[ListingID] AS OwnerListingID
,c.[ListingID] AS ListingListingID
,c.[LevelID]
,(SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM BD_Storefront WHERE (UserID = @passedUserID) AND (ProductVariantID = 1) AND (Status = 1)) AS ActiveBronze
,(SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM BD_Storefront WHERE (UserID = @passedUserID) AND (ProductVariantID = 2) AND (Status = 1)) AS ActiveSilver
,(SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM BD_Storefront WHERE (UserID = @passedUserID) AND (ProductVariantID = 3) AND (Status = 1)) AS ActiveGold
,(SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM BD_Storefront WHERE (UserID = @passedUserID) AND (ProductVariantID = 4) AND (Status = 1)) AS ActivePlatinum
,(SELECT COUNT(ListingID) FROM BD_ListingOwner WHERE (UserID = @passedUserID)

FROM [BD_Storefront] a
JOIN [BD_ListingOwner] b
ON a.[UserID] = b.[UserID]
JOIN [BD_Listing] c
ON b.[ListingID] = c.[ListingID]
WHERE a.[UserID] = @passedUserID
AND Status = 1
```

As you can see, I'm not quite sure how to analyse the BD_Listing table to know how many listing of each type the particular user has already created, and subtracting that amount from each of the SUMS above to get the remaining allowed.

If anyone could help me it would be incredibly awesome.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not totally clear, but is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT lsum.UserID
      ,lsum.LevelID
      ,SUM(ISNULL(sf.Quantity,0)) Active
      ,lsum.ListingTotal-SUM(ISNULL(sf.Quantity,0)) Remaining
FROM
    (SELECT  lo.UserID
            ,l.LevelID-3 LevelID
            ,COUNT(l.Active) ListingTotal
     FROM [BD_Listing] l 
         INNER JOIN
         [BD_ListingOwner] lo ON lo.[ListingID] = l.[ListingID]
     WHERE l.Active=1
     GROUP BY lo.UserID
            ,l.LevelID) lsum
     LEFT JOIN 
     [BD_Storefront] sf ON sf.[UserID] = lsum.[UserID]
                           AND
                           sf.VariantID=lsum.LevelID
                           AND sf.Status = 1
GROUP BY lsum.UserID
         ,lsum.LevelID
         ,lsum.ListingTotal
```

Please see this [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09971/1)

Comment: I was able to use a portion of this. My work-flow changed slightly which caused my delay. Thank you so much for your help!